# Visual studio 2008 isn't recognizing DevExpress

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I have been working in Visual Studio which has DevExpress. My project now doesn't recognize DevExpress so I now have 102 errors on lines like:

```
GroupHeader1.GroupFields.Add(New DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.GroupField("name"))

Friend WithEvents XrPageInfo1 As DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRPageInfo
```

In addition to this when I try to go to the designer for my DevExpress report it can't load the designer :

"The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: rptAll --- The base class 'Object' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built."

Yet when I look in my toolbox the DevExpress tools (XRLine, XRLabel...) are still shown and DevExpress is still located in my reference folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. If anyone comes across this problem for me I had two different versions of DevExpress in the reference folder (under the Solution Explorer). To solve this you have to remove one of the versions. The easiest way is to convert the earlier version to the later one and thus all references will be the same version.

One way is to use the Project Converter within the DevExpress folder under your programs menu and run it on your project folder.

Comment: This happened to me as well, but I hadn't changed any references. I was just working on a form. How bizarre.